# Inserting data into multiple tables using single RadDataForm with EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, entitydatasource

I have a scenario where in I have to insert data into multiple tables using a single RadDataForm with EntityDataSource

Following are the three tables and Columns
ComType:  Id, ConType

ContactDetail:  Id, ContactName, City

ContactCom: Id, ContactDetailsId, ComTypeId, ComValue

**The point is I am able to insert into single table but not able to insert into multiple tables.**

[

```
<asp:Label ID="ComValueLabel3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ComValueTextBox" CssClass="rdfLabel rdfBlock" Text="ComValue"></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="ComValueTextBox" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" Text='<%# Bind("ComValue") %>' WrapperCssClass="rdfInput" />
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dz5L.png)

​

**Following is the syntax of calling other tables columns while insertion**

```
    <asp:Label ID="ContactNameLabel2"runat="server"AssociatedControlID="ContactNameTextBox"
     CssClass="rdfLabel rdfBlock" Text="ContactName"></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="ContactNameTextBox" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" Text='<%# Bind("ContactDetail.ContactName") %>' WrapperCssClass="rdfInput" />

<asp:Label ID="CityLabel2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CityTextBox" CssClass="rdfLabel rdfBlock" Text="City"></asp:Label>
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" RenderMode="Lightweight" Text='<%# Bind("ContactDetail.City") %>' WrapperCssClass="rdfInput" />
```

**EntityDataSource Code:**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=sampleEntities" DefaultContainerName="sampleEntities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"EntitySetName="ContactComs" EntityTypeFilter="ContactCom" Include="ContactDetail,ComType"></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I am unable to call the columns of other tables which are in include method

Here I am attaching the sample DB and full code of my scenario

How can I accomplish this

Thanks In Advance

​

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny5Y3.png)

Comment: Please any one help me on this scenario. Its very urgent. It might be simple but i'm unable to do. Thanks in advance